# I have been facing problems in instaling MeteorJs via terminal in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-installation

I have a Ubuntu 16.04 installed in my system,
when i try to install meteor via terminal using the command

```
sudo curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh
```

I recieve the following in my terminal

```
~$ sudo curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh


 % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  6675    0  6675    0     0   3333      0 --:--:--  0:00:02 --:--:--  3334
Downloading Meteor distribution
                                                                           1.1%
curl: (56) GnuTLS recv error (-9): A TLS packet with unexpected length was received.

gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
Installation failed.
```

Comment: Got it working?

Comment: Mind sharing what helped you get it working, or if found the solution in the answers below, marking the answer as solution?

Comment: I saved the meteor.sh in my computer then installed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your internet connection. Try again over different network. Still not working?

Sometimes, although a response might leave the server in peace, it does get to us in pieces (I mean as incomplete)

You can do this:

- Visit https://install.meteor.com/
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> to save as `meteor.sh`
- Change directory to where you downloaded the file to,
- You may have to `chmod +x ./meteor.sh` then run..
- `sudo ./meteor.sh`

Answer (score -2):

Thanks @rexford for the answer. I am running Ubuntu 14.04 (LTS), had the same issue.

I fixed the problem following the steps bellow-

- Visit https://install.meteor.com
- Save the file- press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> as `meteor.sh`
- Open terminal and change the directory to where you downloaded the file
- Run this command to make the file executable: `chmod 755 meteor.sh`
- Now execute the file: `./meteor.sh`. Here `sudo` is not necessary.

Comment: This is mostly the same as rexford's answer. Consider [editing](http://askubuntu.com/posts/766594/edit) it if you want to suggest corrections.